# Windows 10 Home Activation Tab Crashes

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine

I want to upgrade from Windows 10 Home (which came pre-installed with the HP Spectre laptop) to Windows 10 Professional so I can run Virtual Machines.  I think I can do this on the activation tab, but it crashes.  This is in the event log.

> Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version:
>      10.0.15063.502, time stamp: 0x7c8bd05a Faulting module name: SettingsHandlers_nt.dll, version: 10.0.15063.540, time stamp:
>   0xdfd95a95 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x00000000000890b3 Faulting process id: 0x1130 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d32a6107bd9245 Faulting application path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe Faulting module
>   path: C:\Windows\System32\SettingsHandlers_nt.dll Report Id:
>   3d42469c-5946-4e8f-884e-b6d162e8e121 Faulting package full name:
>   windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>   microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel

Comment: [VWware Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/player/playerpro-evaluation.html) runs very well on Home editions of Windows. It is free for home, non-commercial use. The latest releases are for 64-bit Windows only, though earlier versions can be found which ran on 32-bit.

Comment: If you already bought a license, contact Microsoft. This could be a bug.

Comment: @DanielB Everything came pre-installed with the computer.  I didn't buy Windows 10 Home or Pro directly

Comment: [create a crash dump](https://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57) and share the dmp. I'll analyze it and look if I can see anything useful.

Comment: You should install KB4034674

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B25lgbFABqmCeXVzUXdOUnYtQlU

Comment: @Ramhound that was already installed

Comment: Are you attempting to activate through the Control Panel or the UWP Settings application?  I missed the fact the dll was 10.0.15063.540 and not 10.0.15063.502.

Comment: I think its UWP.  I just type Activation into the 'Cortana Bar' and it autocompletes

Comment: there is an issue and the the settings app crashes while getting the error (GetErrorDescription). I've send the dump to MSFT for more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with the 'Creators Update', but the 'Creators Update' would not install in the normal fashion, I had to download it manually first.